# TeamCity Agent unable to connect ServerUrl

Tags: teamcity, agent

Hi I have installed teamcity and now trying to build a visual studio project. The thing is my agent remains disconnected and I tried to solve it as delete the current agent and reinstalled it. While I was installing the agent on the agent configuration window when I pressed save button an information window appeared saying that 'unable to connect serverUrl' and asks me if I wanted to continue anyway.. It is the default serverUrl comes with installiation
as http : // BuildServer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be that teamcity works with visual svn so if you want to add project you should make sure that teamcity recognizes the svn and projects in it. It is very easy after installing svn server to computer where teamcity installed.